# How to assign value to datetime-local in a Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I am unable to assign value to `datetime-local element in a form.

**Code from template:**

[image: Code from HTML template]

**Code from typescript file:**

```
let dateTime : Date = new Date();

this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({    
  'dateTime': new FormControl(dateTime),
});
```

**Result:**

[image]

What is the proper way to assign date & time to datetime-local using typescript

Comment: type datetime-local is a "string" type, so you can do this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({    
      'dateTime': '2017-06-01T08:30',
    });. Anyway, I suggested NOT use type datetime-local. This don't work in all navigators (e.g. you see as "normal" input in FireFox)

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for your suggestion. Hard coded string works perfectly but I want to assign system's current date and time to the datetime-local.

Comment: use new Date().toString() or some like, see, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`datetime-local` requires value in specific format **(yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm)**

You can try the following,

```js
const dateTime = new Date();
this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({    
  dateTime: new FormControl(dateTime.toISOString().substring(0, 16)),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [official docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#value). Output from the console:

> The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

I used `DatePipe` for this, but you could go with `formatDate` also (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456890/how-to-convert-date-to-string-into-the-format-yyyy-mm-dd-in-typescript) for more).

In your component:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(
    private datePipe: DatePipe
)

ngOnInit() {
    this.dateControl.setValue(this.datePipe.transform(this.defaultValues, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'));
}
```

In your module declarations (e.g. app.module.ts) add `DatePipe`:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        // ...
    ],
    imports: [
        // ...

    ],
    providers: [
        DatePipe,
        // ...
    ],
    exports: // ...
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```