# How to convert Date to String into the format yyyy-mm-dd in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, date

How to convert Date to String into the format **yyyy-mm-dd** in typescript

Now I am getting the date as **Fri Mar 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)**

I only need date in the format **"2017-03-24"**
from that and without any timezones and timezone conversions

Comment: show us the code you have so far

Comment: If you're using Angular, you should use the Date pipe. Look at this question, it's almost identical (assuming you're using Angular): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754586/format-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-using-pipes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using Angular, you may import DatePipe, or FormatDate into your component.ts to handle that. You may read more about the various [date/time formats](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) you can pass as the parameters.

1) DatePipe:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {   

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    return this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }
}
```

Do not forget to add DatePipe to your providers in your module.

```
providers: [DatePipe]
```

2) formatDate:

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    return formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', this.locale);
  }
}
```

Comment: pipe can't be injected, they have to be instanciated (or instanciated then injected through a token or a factory)

Comment: I tried the first method it worked. Thanks - @wentjun

Comment: Cool, @Shiny! All the best with your project, mate!